# Do connectors in REST include component interfaces?

Tags: rest

My question is more conceptual than technical. I'm trying to understand connectors in REST, and in my mind they seem analogous to paths or connections in a network. So is a connector in REST just a channel of communication, or does it also include interfaces on the endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the documentation, I guess:

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm

On 5.2.2 of Fielding's paper, he defines and explains the connectors. The answer to my question is, "Yes, connectors include interfaces." In fact, they seem to be little more than interfaces.

A connector is more likely to be just one endpoint, but the definition for connectors is intentionally loose to include any part of a RESTful system that facilitates communication between the components. So a client component will delegate communication to a client connector which in turn communicates with a server connector that handles communication for its respective server component. A tunnel connector, on the other hand might include both of its endpoints.

Another point I found useful while reading Fielding's paper is that connectors benefit just as much from the uniform interface as any component. Since server/client/resolver/etc. connectors are all working on URIs, matters are greatly simplified.